# How to make div not overlap another div inside parent div

Tags: html, css

So basically I have mainDiv, which is pretty much size of body. 
In mainDiv there are 2 divs which are supposed to be next to each other and they are until resize or mobile device comes in. Problem is that second div completely overlaps first one.

[Desired outcome http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/473/yn9x.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/473/yn9x.jpg)

```
#mainDiv { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 670px;
}

#mainDiv div {
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

Rest of code: http://jsfiddle.net/fDELs/2/

- I couldn't use width: [value]% because I don't need both divs always to be shown while zooming in (plus it still starts horizontally eating first div).
- I can't use float: left or float:right, because if page gets wider then empty area appears between 2 divs.

Right now I have js workaround solution, which checks the width and position of first div and sets 'left' property of second one, but I would love to do it in CSS.

Comment: A diagram of the desired result would be helpful.

Comment: PS: I need div2 to be relative to first div not body left as div2 has to start where div1 ends.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `position: relative` and `top` values from divs, and use `margin-top` instead.

```
#mainDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 670px;
}

#mainDiv div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

#first {
    margin-top: 170px;
}

#second {
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 65px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDELs/3/)

Comment: fiddle gives me 2 divs which are on top of each and have pretty big white space between them. Also margin-top is also a bad way to start from, because I don't want constants to follow me around. That's why I'm trying to do this with CSS instead of javascript (read at the end)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bSK6p/1/

Resize the window and see what happens.

```
#mainDiv { 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#mainDiv div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (min-width:300px){
    #mainDiv { 
        height: 670px;
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
    }

    #first {
        -webkit-flex: none;
        flex: none;
    }

    #second {
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        height: 400px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirm that this works on PC, but not on handheld devices. Looking for other solutions as well. Also flex is not supported by IE and safari. Anyways +1 for partial solution.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [http://jsfiddle.net/bSK6p/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/bSK6p/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, I know, but people are still viewing it when they search for this same issue on Google.... cause that's how I landed here, and none of the solutions given worked for me.

For those of you who were looking for a solution to the same problem I was (getting divs to sit side by side without overlapping each other) then my post is for you. I don't know if this was the answer to the original poster though but it might be close?

I was trying to get 3 div's to sit side by side. What did it for me was giving each class for each div, their own "float:left;" attribute. So all three div's need to float left. I also had to set the widths so they would not push each other down (your width's should add up to a total of 100% or less) and I set the heights the same for each, 100px although heights could vary I think. Another thing, probably you should set the background-size to contain and background-repeat to no-repeat. You can set the background-position however you like.

```css
.image1Div{
 background-image:url(images/image1.png);
 background-size:contain;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 width:32%;
 height:100px;
 float:left;
}

.image2Div {
 background-image:url(images/image2.png);
 background-size:contain;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 width:32%;
 height:100px;
 float:left;
}

.imgage3Div{
 background-image:url(images/image3.png);
 background-size:contain;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 width:32%;
 height:100px;
 float:left;
}
```

Basically, from what I can tell, the float left attribute tells the object to float to the left of the object next to it. Since each object is sitting to the left of another, and you also don't want them overlapping, just adding float:left seems to work. As for making sizes match, or two halves of an image match, that has more to do with your photo editing than anything else I think, because you'll need the heights to be exactly the same for both images and then your width's need to be the correct ratios as well. Yeah, you might be looking to do some magic with CSS.... but I can't picture it working if you're going for a site that is responsive to different browsers on different screen sizes.... Also, I wasn't able to see the picture example you posted. It seems to have been taken down.

ANYWAY, like I said, this is for those of you who googled "how to make my div's not overlap" or something like that, and ended up at this post.... So I hope this helps somebody. Google failed me again....

Ah, sorry, I just realized you were trying to get them to work inside a parent DIV, but actually, this does work inside a parent DIV. You just need to make sure the parent DIV has a matching height to the other divs you want to fit inside it.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer has little to do with what you posted here and can only be ascertianed by looking at your complete fiddle.

The problem is that you have a both interior divs being relatively positioned from the same point. The div full of content is only pushed down a bit and the one with almost no content is pushed down into the middle of that.

```
#first {
    top: 170px;
}

#second { 
    height: 400px;
    top: 65px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing position:relative from #mainDiv div seems to do the trick

```
#mainDiv div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fDELs/4/

Comment: divs are on top of each other on my screen without resizing.

Comment: Just saw the diagram: I don't know if this helps but you could specify a max-width value on the #second div http://jsfiddle.net/fDELs/8/ even if its incorrect I think you'll need some kind of width attribute in order to get it to float as you want. (I also made the assumption that your weren't aren't going to fill you second div with a huge unbroken string, considering those are a pain to style)