# How to stop div from overlapping three smaller one

Tags: html, css

My question is the following when I load it up in my browser the expanded div seems to contain the three smaller ones. The wished result is just that the div is under the three ones. I already tried putting `float:left` on the expanded one but then my footer overlaps all. I have already looked onto the forum for a solution but did not find anything fitting.

[How to make div not overlap another div inside parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618789/how-to-make-div-not-overlap-another-div-inside-parent-div)

Is the post that I have found.

```css
div#content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  position: relative;
}

#one,
#two,
#three {
  width: 30.75%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 25px 10px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#one,
#two {
  float: left;
}

#three {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

#expanded {
  width: 97%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 25px 10px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

footer{
  margin: 50px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1F1F1F;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 1px 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="expanded">
    <a id="boxtitle-ex" href="#">titel 4</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <footer> Footer </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */

div#content-wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  position: relative;
}
#one, #two, #three {
  width: 30.75%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 25px 10px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#one, #two { float: left; }
#three { float: left; clear: none; }

#expanded{
  width: 97%;
  float:left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 25px 10px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
footer{
  margin: 50px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
  background-color: #1F1F1F;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 1px 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="expanded">
    <a id="boxtitle-ex" href="#">titel 4</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 1</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 2</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <a id="boxtitle" href="#">titel 3</a>
    <p>L
  </div>
  <footer> Footer </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but the same result got me just adding `float: left;`. Now my problem is that my footer is overlapping everything. But I think this is another question.

Comment: @AndySchneider I cant see footer in the code, if you add float to that too and width 97% like you did for `div#expanded` it will come below the `div#expanded`.

Comment: My footer is in my content-wrapper and setting the width to 97% does not help unfortunately. But thank you anyway you really helped me

Comment: @AndySchneider if you want update your question will try to help

Comment: I have updated my question the footer is only overlapping if I add something under the expanded one @Naren Murali

Comment: @AndySchneider I have tried the `float:left` it works fine, I updated my answer, if you face some issue, you can open the console and start playing around with the CSS, basically uncheck the CSS or add new CSS, till the issue is resolved, refer [using the console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)